# How would you implement instant messaging on Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-sql-database, instant-messaging

Hi we are thinking to implement a chat feature in our web app. (MVC 3 running on Azure) like Facebook or Gmail applications.

So the idea about this question is to have your technical architecture opinion about it.

How would you design it and which services you would use (worker role, queue, blob, Sql azure etc.).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instant Messaging is about asynchronous delivery of messages between multiple publishers and subscribers.  This sounds like a perfect recipe for Azure Queues.

If the number of users who will use this feature is small, you can create a queue per recipient.  Web-app would drop a message onto the recipient's queue and would check queue of its own user.

The positive about this approach is its simplicity  The downside of this approach is the frequency of checking the queues per user and the cost associated with that.

If you have 10,000 users logged into IM and the app is checking their queue's once per second, that's 1penny per second.  Which translates to ~$26k/month.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure Service Bus provides Publish-Subscribe messaging with Topics that can be used for this scenario. You can see a Silverlight based Chat sample for this: http://servicebus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9715

In addition you can see a Multi-tier app sample that shows using Service Bus Topics/Subscriptions from Web/Worker roles here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Multi-Tier-application-6c033cad